# WP Multisite get current page from other Blog

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have a wordpress page where i have Menu Items, content and more.
Now the idea is to have two domains they can go to:

The default one: *link.de/page*

And a second one at: *blog.link.de/page*

The plan is, that the second domain has the same contents as the default one. The only thing that would be different is the domain people will would be on.

This is the hard part, i must include the content from the default page here.

Step 1 was, include the Menu from the default one and change the links via Walker.

> Now i need ideas how i can display the content from a page which has
>   the same name as the current.

If you think "why you need multisite, when the content is the same"

> The content can be change, when the current page exists on the current blog

Hope you can help me...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CNAME record for this:

That CNAME could point to the original server. And when you point a CNAME, you also directly have that subdomain.

You should also set your site home and base url to the url of the main website so that if you click on something in the second one it leads you to the main domain. And not to a dead page.

Hope that works.

Source(Shold definitely read): 

https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/how-to-point-domains-to-mapped-wp-multisite-subdomains?utm_expid=3606929-92.rprqzZQVQVO9C0D8ZR2AsQ.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.nl%2F

Comment: Hm, i dont think that it worked. But thanks! When i click my menu items the link is the right "sub.link.de/page" -> here i got a 404 <- this is clear cause the page dont exist. What WordPress should do here is to show the content from blog 1 but i dont know how ...

Comment: When page not found, then get the page from the default blog (1) and query this normaly <- this is how i need it <- categories and other types must work here too.

Comment: Would you then just want  it to all redirect to the main site? So the second one is basically a dummy?

Comment: Changed my answer.  Try again.

Comment: I just use Broadcast Plugin, this is what I need. Thanks for your help!